# Prawn Ruby Document generate pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

```
 def generate_report
    tablica = []
    tablica << 1
    Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf") { tablica.each { |a| text a } }
  end
```

Why this code doesn't work in Prawn??? Which code is correct??

Comment: OK I SOLVED IT IT SHOULD BE: require "rubygems"
require "prawn"
tablica  =[]
words ="Hello world"
words2 ="AAA"
tablica <<words
tablica <<words2

Prawn::Document.generate "example2.pdf" do |pdf|
   tablica.each do |element|
        pdf.text element

    end

end

Comment: Not sure how that's "solving it" any differently than what the two answers already said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're passing a number, not a string.

```
def generate_report
  tablica = []
  tablica << 1
  Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf") { tablica.each { |a| text "#{a}" } }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require 'prawn'

def generate_report
  tablica = []
  tablica << 10
  Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf") { tablica.each { |a| text a.to_s } }
end

generate_report
```

You should pass parameter as 'string' in `text` method.